# Required persistence-unit on Payara / Glassfish 5

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, persistence, payara

I'm trying to deploy a project which in his persistence.xml contains several persistente-unit.

In our use-case, we have to deploy in different servers. Most of them just have one of that pool names configured.

Older versions of Glassfish / Payara allowed us to deploy under this circumstances.

Now the server throws an exception, "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: poolName not found", which doesn't allow us to deploy. It seems to be mandatory to have all persistence pools registered on the server.

Is there some way to tell the server to NOT check if all persistence-unit exists or set persistence-units as not required or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding following JVM option to your domain.xml:

```
<jvm-options>-Ddeployment.resource.validation=false</jvm-options>
```

If you want to use the admin console you can execute following command:

```
asadmin create-jvm-options -Ddeployment.resource.validation=false
```